# Large dynamic array in c++

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, overflow

Short problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double **T;
    long int L_size;
    long int R_size = 100000;
    long int i,j;

    cout << "enter L_size:";
    cin >> L_size;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    cout << L_size*R_size << endl;
    cout << sizeof(double)*L_size*R_size << endl;

    T = new double *[L_size];
    for (i=0;i<L_size;i++)
    {
        T[i] = new double[R_size];
    }

    cout << "press enter to fill array" << endl;
    getchar();
    for (i=0;i<L_size;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<R_size;j++)
        {
            T[i][j] = 10.0;
        }
    }
    cout << "allocated" << endl;


    for (i=0;i<L_size;i++)
    {
        delete[] T[i];
    }
    delete [] T;
    cout << "press enter to close" << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

with 2GB of RAM (on 32bit OS) I can't make it work with `L_size = 3000` which is pretty obvious since it would need approx. 2.4GB.

But when I start 2 copies of above program each with `L_size = 1500` it works - really slow but finally both returns `allocated` in console.
So the question is - how is that possible? Is it related to virtual memory?

It is possible to have one big array stored in virtual memory while operating on another - within one program?

Thx.

Comment: I'd expect that it is very much related to the OS' ability to swap out inactive memory (i.e. a suspended (in preemptive multi-tasking terms) app) and swap in another one.

Comment: Is this on a 32bit OS or on a 64bit OS?

Comment: As a side note, you are not allocating "one big array", but L_size+1 R_size arrays.  You are probably bumping into the addressable memory limitation for the 32-bit OS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  The operating system will allow you to allocate up to 2GB of RAM per process.  When you start two copies, it will let this grow using virtual memory, which will be very, very slow (since it's using the hard drive), but still function.

Comment: It is possible to have one big array stored in virtual memory while operating on another - within one program?

Comment: A 32-bit program is limited in how much total memory it can use, because the pointers don't have enough bits to address it all. That's why 64 bits is becoming more popular.

Comment: Yes.  On a 64bit system, your first test case ~might~ have worked (if you have enough swap specifed) - but it would be very slow.  It's technically possible to allocate >2gb, even in a 32bit Windows program, but quite a bit more difficult.  (Search for /3GB switch for details, if you're curious.)

Comment: Win32 also offers the "Address Windowing Extension" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366527%28VS.85%29.aspx to allow a process to use more than 4 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's virtual memory.  With L_size = 1500, you can start the first instance and it will be able to allocate the required memory.  When you start the second instance, the memory allocated by the first instance is paged out to disk, making room in RAM for the second instance.

The amount of RAM you can allocate at any one time and in any one process depends not only on the amount of physical RAM and virtual memory (page file size) you have available, but also on the width of your memory addresses.  On a 64-bit machine, you will be able to allocate much more memory in a single process than you would be able to on a 32-bit machine.